# Meteor: Unable to connect / run commands on another meteor server

Tags: meteor

Let's say I have two different Meteor servers: an application server (running on port 3000) which hosts all of the business logic, and a job queue server (running on port 6000) that does background tasks.

My application server is where I define a bunch of collections, attach SimpleSchema to those collections, and produce jobs.

The job queue server needs to be able to connect to the application server so it can use it's collections, find jobs to work on, etc. I have tried the following on the job queue server:

```
console.log('one');

const Followers = new Mongo.Collection('followers', {
  connection: DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000'),
});

console.log('two');

Followers.insert({
  f: 'some',
  t: 'crap',
});

console.log('three');
```

`Followers` is a valid collection defined on the application server, so I'd expect a few things to happen here:

1. An update operation should be attempted
2. SimpleSchema on the application server should kick in and reject it, since the payload is... crap :)
3. I'd expect to see all 3 console.log statements in the console, or at least an error from the failure in #2 above.

However this hasn't been the case. The job queue server gets hung up on the update command and can't get past it. All I see in the console is:

```
I20170711-06:12:40.070(-4)? one               
I20170711-06:12:40.091(-4)? two
```

with no error messages. I suspect it is because the job queue server is not properly connecting to the application server. However, I'm not getting any error messages in the console so I'm clueless at this point as to what is wrong.

I have tried changing the connection string protocol to `http`, `https`, `ws`, no protocol... all to no avail. What am I missing here? Also wondering about authentication...how does my application server know that the incoming server ddp connection is trustworthy?

The only way I have been able to write to MongoDB from the job queue server is to omit the connection string altogether, but this bypasses the SimpleSchema I have set up on the application server and allows me to submit crap into Mongo documents (I am assuming using DDP.connect to specify a remote collection with an attached schema will prevent this (?)).

If anyone could help shed some light on this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does the console of the application server is also free of errors?

Comment: Correct, no errors on either side. I just tried outputting `connection.status().status` to console on a 1 second interval on the job queue server and it's saying the connection is "waiting" indefinitely...